# How to change EF decimal truncation behaviour

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

In entity framework, if you set the precision on a decimal column in your database to say 10,2, and update it in your EDMX, it will automatically truncate any decimals to 2 decimal places, correct?

I would prefer that it blow up in my face with an exception if I give it a number with a bunch of decimal places than have it silently truncate it, because it means I've not validated my data properly.

Is there a setting that I can set this? or am I going to have to attach to the savingchanges method and do some reflection?

**To clarify with an example:**

If I had a table called Invoice with a column called Amount. In my database this is a decimal(10,2) column, this is reflected in the EDMX, my entity says that this has a precision of 10 and a scale of 2.

Then in my code, lets say the user creates an invoice and they enter 10.23456 as the amount, I've forgotten to add some sort of clientside validation for this, so the amount gets sent to the server, my controller then saves an invoice with an amount of 10.23456. Entity framework will truncate this to 10.23 and be done with it.

What I want is this:
If I were to try and save an invoice with 10.23456 as the amount, EF sees that I have got a more precise value than my entity allows, and throws an exception. So this way my failure to validate inputs properly is discovered straight away.

Comment: can you clarify the question with an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can«t make this configuration on the Entity Framework. But if you override your class and add some validation metadata on the properties, it will blow on you face with the validation error. 
For example

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$",
                   ErrorMessage = "ERROR MESSAGE")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

OR

```
[StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 0, ErrorMessage = "ERROR MESSAGE")]
public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately I don't think that will help in our situation, as we're looking at decimal values with a certain amount of decimal places and we're hoping for an exception instead of a validation message. We're still adding validation into our client side but we want an exception thrown as a last line of defense.